# iOS how to debug crashes without a stack trace like : [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array?

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, nsarray

I'm  trying to dismiss a modal view controller and am getting the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

At one point I spent 4 hours trying to debug such error. Can anyone tell me if there's a way to look at stack traces for such errors to understand which object caused the incorrect access?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Xcode 4 you can set an exception breakpoint in the breakpoint editor. Every time an exception is thrown (or caught depending on how you set it up), your application will pause on the line that threw the exception.

Comment: I wish I could combine the two answers. I did not know I could break on exceptions.

Comment: Why would you ever *not* want this?

Comment: With iOS7 this breakpoint also triggers on constraint based exceptions, which can be very annoying if you are trying to work on something else at the moment.

Answer (score 23):

if you are running in the debugger, then absolutely you should be able to see the actual line that the exception is being thrown on.

add an exception breakpoint by clicking the breakpoints tab at the top of the left pane, then click the plus sign at the lower left. Add an exception breakpoint.

[image]