# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    if (indexPath.row >= [CatArray count])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    if(searching)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text=[ListOfArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

     else
     {
             NSString *cellv=[CatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             cell.textLabel.text=cellv;
     }
     return cell;
}
```

When I click on object at Index 0. It is working fine but when click on Index 1 and above my program show `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]` error. I can't find how to fix this error.

Please help.

Comment: please show what have you written in your 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath...'

Comment: your CatArray has only one object at index - 0. Check is there any object at index 1, indexpath.row = 1 in diapason 0 .. 0, or didSelectRowAtIndexPath you operate with another Array that do not have object atIndex:1

Comment: @zaph, notice there are two arrays, the bounds are checked on one of them, but not the searching one:

Comment: if you are looking to debug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569033/ios-how-to-debug-crashes-without-a-stack-trace-like-nsarraym-objectatindex/8569059#8569059

Comment: @zaph notice my upvote :)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my quiz. I already found the error it is not in this function. Causing problem is in my didSelectRow part. :D

Answer (score 3):

While `CatArray` count is checked `ListOfArray` count isn't.

Turn on break on exception and find out which line is causing the exception.
[image]

Also note that returning nil is an error, from the docs:

> An object inheriting from UITableViewCell that the table view can use
>   for the specified row. An assertion is raised if you return nil. –

Answer (score 1):

The tip-off that you should rethink your code appears in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method here:

```
if (indexPath.row >= [CatArray count])
{
    return nil;
}
```

That condition will never occur if your code answers numberOfRowsInSection properly, with the count of the appropriate array.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (searching)? [ListOfArray count] : [CatArray count];
}
```

Comment: additionally, the tableView will raise an assertion if nil is returned from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message should be quite clear, you are looking for an object in the index which is beyond the bounds of your array.

Here the message: *index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]* means you are looking for object at index 1, but the array itself only has objects at index between 0 to 0. An array index starts from 0.

Try to check your *CatArray* or *ListOfArray* whether they have the objects that you want in the first place. Also, check how you calculate the return value of table view data source `numberOfRowsInSection`.