# sigbrt error (Xcode 4.6)

Tags: objective-c

I've been trying to put together an app (using Xcode 4.6.3) that has many buttons and they have a similar code, but when I try to test it, the debugger comes up. I'm just learning Objective C and don't really know how to fix this problem. I was able to use a few breakpoints to get this set of code in the debugger,

```
CoreFoundation`-[NSException raise]:
0x1d19fa0:  pushl  %ebp
0x1d19fa1:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1d19fa3:  subl   $8, %esp
0x1d19fa6:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x1d19fa9:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1d19fac:  calll  0x1d645a4                 ; symbol stub for: objc_exception_throw
0x1d19fb1:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)
```

I don't understand what this means. Can someone tell me how I can fix this? If you need more info I'll try to get it to you. Thanks!

Comment: see my answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569033/ios-how-to-debug-crashes-without-a-stack-trace-like-nsarraym-objectatindex/8569059#8569059

Comment: there is an exception raised, which means that something is wrong somewhere, once you have a breakpoint you can try to figure it out...

Comment: I don't know how you managed to break in the middle of a CF exception handling frame, but this is not helpful.  What triggers the exception? (take a look at the stack trace in the left pane)  Also, what does this have to do with Xcode?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is find out how to fix the problem so that I can run the app, It just pauses it.

Comment: 0 -[NSException raise] is the first thing it highlights. The object that it highlights is 0x1d19fa0:  pushl  %ebp, after that, it says Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1

Comment: OK, now find the stack trace leading up to that exception in the left-most pane

Comment: try `po $rax` in the debugger, that is the location of the address to the NSException object, not sure if it will work after the crash, but if you turn on the exception breakpoint it certainly will.

Comment: Put an exception breakpoint by clicking on the breakpoint navigator, then click on the "+" icon on bottom left, and select "Add exception breakpoint". You'll be able to see all the stack trace, so you'll know which is the last method that you called that has probably messed up things.

Comment: the last two in the stack are ``0x10cef84:  calll  0x10e336e

Comment: and, symbol stub for: __cxa_throw

Comment: The odd thing is that I'm trying to put in several buttons in. When I have one, the program works like a charm, and when the other buttons don't have any code attached to them.